# Colouring Bifurcation Diagram

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, graphics, mathematical-optimization, color

I need to plot the bifurcation diagram for the function given below.

```
g[x_, r_] := 6 x^2 + r x^4 + x^6 

Plot[g[x, -4.9], {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

### Bifurcation

Code for bifurcation is burrowed from [Coloring Bifurcation Diagram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32370/84456) question:

```
CClear[NotComplexQ];
NotComplexQ[c_Complex] := False;
NotComplexQ[c_] := True

CartProd[l_] := Outer[List, l[[1]], l[[2]]]

ArreglaLista[l_] := Select[Map[(x /. #) &, Flatten[l]], NotComplexQ]

Points = Flatten[
   Map[CartProd, 
    Table[{{r}, ArreglaLista[NSolve[g2[x, r] == 0, x]]}, {r, -20, 10, 
      0.01}]], 2];
ListPlot[Points]
```

[image]

---

### Colouring

I've also borrowed the code from [the answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32374/84456) by @[Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) to the above-mentioned question, however, it does not work for my problem. How to modify it to get the desired result?

```
unstable = Select[Points, First@# >= 0 && Last@# == 0 &];
stable = 
  SortBy[#, 
     First] & /@ (Append[#, {0, 0}] & /@ (GatherBy[
       Complement[Points, unstable], Sign@Last@# &]));

ListPlot[stable~Join~{unstable}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Dashing[0.01]], 
   Directive[ Blue, Dashing[0.01]], 
   Directive[ Red, Dashing[0.008]], 
   Directive[ Blue, Dashing[0.1]]}]
```

[image]

> I want the stable line for **r>0** to be *solid blue*, the stable
> lines for **r<0** to be in *dashed blue line* and the unstable lines
> to be *red dashed*.
>
> Is there any general method to do it?

Please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ContourPlot` to make such 1D bifurcation diagrams easily as in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/241214/6358), using `ConditionalExpression` to handle the stability analysis.  I assume `g[x, r]` is some kind of potential, not `x'[t]`, so that an equilibrium is where `D[g[x, r], x]==0` and is stable if `D[g[x, r], {x, 2}]>0`.

```
g[x_, r_] = 6  x^2 + r  x^4 + x^6;
dg[x_, r_] = D[g[x, r], x];
dg2[x_, r_] = D[g[x, r], {x, 2}];

ContourPlot[{
  ConditionalExpression[dg[x, r], dg2[x, r] > 0 && r > 0] == 0,
  ConditionalExpression[dg[x, r], dg2[x, r] > 0 && r < 0] == 0,
  ConditionalExpression[dg[x, r], dg2[x, r] < 0] == 0
}, {r, -20, 10}, {x, -5, 5},
ContourStyle -> {{Blue}, {Blue, Dashed}, {Red, Dashed}}, MaxRecursion -> 3, FrameLabel -> {"r", "x"}]
```

[image]

This matches your description but I suspect it isn't what you want.  Maybe this is more like it?

```
ContourPlot[{
  ConditionalExpression[dg[x, r], dg2[x, r] > 0 && Abs[x] < 0.1] == 0,
  ConditionalExpression[dg[x, r], dg2[x, r] > 0 && Abs[x] > 0.1] == 0,
  ConditionalExpression[dg[x, r], dg2[x, r] < 0] == 0
}, {r, -20, 10}, {x, -5, 5},
ContourStyle -> {{Blue}, {Blue, Dashed}, {Red, Dashed}}, MaxRecursion -> 3, FrameLabel -> {"r", "x"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ChrisK

Comment: Just one question, Why do you have taken `&& Abs[x] < 0.1]` and `&& Abs[x] >0.1]`?? Why 0.1 and how is it different from $r>0$ and $r<0$????

Comment: @user444 I was just guessing that you wanted a graph like the second one, not the first - if that's not correct I can remove the second

Comment: It's alright. I was just curious to know how is different is it from what I asked.

Comment: The middle line can be defined by `Abs[x] < 0.1` whereas `r > 0` makes the left half of the middle line dashed and the right half solid.